# Largest Amount of Consecutive Odd Integers to Equal a Target

Tags: java, algorithm

I am currently looking to find the largest amount of consecutive odd integers added together to equal a target number.

My current code to find 3 consecutive integers looks like

```
public class consecutiveOdd {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int target = 160701;
        boolean found = false;

        for(int i = 1; i < target; i++){
            if(i + (i+2) + (i+4) == target){
                System.out.print(i + " + " + (i+2) + " + " + (i+4));
                found = true;
            }

         }
         if(!found){
            System.out.println("Sorry none");
         }
     }
}
```

I am thinking there will need to be a while loop building iterations of (i+2) increments but am having trouble with developing a correct algorithm. Any help or tips will be much appreciated!

Best,
Otterman

Comment: Your for loop is going to look at odd sets {1, 3, 5} but also even sets {2, 4, 6}. So you might want to say i+=2 instead of i++. BTW, I like the mathematical solution above much more than a brute-force search.

Comment: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65469.html

Comment: FYI: The answer is **391**: `21 + 23 + 25 + ... + 799 + 801 = 160701`

Comment: Hey, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that the answer is equal to `k (k > 0)`. Then for some odd `i` we can write: `i + (i + 2) + (i + 4) + ... + (i + 2k - 2) = target`. You can see that this is a sum of [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), therefore you can use a well known formula to compute it. Applying the formula we can get:
`i = target/k - k + 1`.

Basing on this formula I would suggest the following algorithm:

1. Iterate over the value of `k`.
2. If `target/k - k + 1` is a positive odd integer, update the answer.

Simple implementation.

```
int answer = -1;
for (int k = 1;; k++) {
    int i = target / k - k + 1;
    if (i <= 0) {
        break;
    }
    // Check if calculated i, can be the start of 'odd' sequence.
    if (target % k == 0 && i % 2 == 1) {
        answer = k;
    }
}
```

The running time of this algorithm is `O(sqrt(target))`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the pattern:

1. For 1 summand, `i = target`
2. For 2 summands, the equation is `2*i + 2 = target`, so `i = (target - 2) / 2`
3. For 3 summands, the equation is `3*i + 6 = target`, so `i = (target - 6) / 3`
4. For 4 summands, the equation is `4*i + 12 = target`, so `i = (target - 12) / 4`

etc. Clearly `i` must be an odd integer in all cases.

You could work out the general expression for `n` summands, and simplify it to show you an algorithm, but you might be able to see an algorithm already...

---

Applying @rossum's suggestion:

1. For 1 summand, `2m + 1 = target`
2. For 2 summands, `2m + 1 = (target - 2) / 2`, so `m = (target - 4) / 4`
3. For 3 summands, `2m + 1 = (target - 6) / 3`, so `m = (target - 9) / 6`
4. For 4 summands, `2m + 1 = (target - 12) / 4`, so `m = (target - 16) / 8`

Comment: Clearly `i` must be an *odd* integer in all cases according to the question.  Use the substitution `i = 2m + 1` and solve for `m` to relax the requirement.  That way `m` can be either odd or even.

Comment: @rossum neat suggestion, I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of a sequence of `n` odd integers, can be calculated as the average value (midpoint `m`) multiplied by the number of values (`n`), so:

```
sum  =  5 + 7 + 9       =  m * n  =  7 * 3  =  21
sum  =  5 + 7 + 9 + 11  =  m * n  =  8 * 4  =  32
```

If `n` is odd then `m` will be odd, and if `n` is even then `m` will be even.

The `first` and `last` numbers of the sequence can be calculated as:

```
first  =  m - n + 1  =  8 - 4 + 1  =  5
last   =  m + n - 1  =  8 + 4 - 1  =  11
```

Other interesting formulas:

```
m  =  sum / n
m  =  (first + last) / 2
last  =  first + (n - 1) * 2  =  first + 2 * n - 2
m  =  (first + first + 2 * n - 2) / 2  =  first + n - 1
```

The *longest* sequence would have to start with the lowest possible `first` value, meaning `1`, so we get:

```
sum  =  m * n  =  (first + n - 1) * n  =  n * n
```

Which means that the longest sequence of any given `sum` can at most be `sqrt(sum)` long.

So starting at `sqrt(sum)`, and searching down until we find a valid `n`:

```
/**
  * Returns length of sequence, or 0 if no sequence can be found
  */
private static int findLongestConsecutiveOddIntegers(int sum) {
    for (int n = (int)Math.sqrt(sum); n > 1; n--) {
        if (sum % n == 0) { // m must be an integer
            int m = sum / n;
            if ((n & 1) == (m & 1)) // If n is odd, mid must be odd. If n is even, m must be even.
                return n;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*Result:*

```
n  =  findLongestConsecutiveOddIntegers(160701)  =  391
m  =  sum / n  =  160701 / 391  =  411
first  =  m - n + 1  =  411 - 391 + 1  =  21
last   =  m + n - 1  =  411 + 391 - 1  =  801
```

Since `sqrt(160701) = 400.875...`, the result was found in **10** iterations (400 to 391, inclusive).

*Conclusion:*

Largest Amount of Consecutive Odd Integers to Equal 160701: **391**

```
21 + 23 + 25 + ... + 799 + 801 = 160701
```